# Array to string conversion with delimiter pipe | in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to form a string from a given array.

Suppose array[1] = gvk, array[2] = gvk1 and array[3] = gvk2, then I need to get these values into a string like:

Mystring = gvk | gvk1 | gvk2

Answer (score 55):

I think you can use the [`array_to_string`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html) function here :

> array_to_string(anyarray, text)    --> text
>   concatenates array elements using supplied delimiter

Example:

```
scalasb=> select array_to_string(ARRAY[1, 2, 3], '~^~');
 array_to_string 
-----------------
 1~^~2~^~3
(1 row)

scalasb=>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [MS SQL to POSTGRES Blogspot](http://mssql-to-postgresql.blogspot.com/2007/12/cool-groupconcat.html) has a demonstration of how to implement a group_concat function in Postgres. It should be pretty straightforward to modify it to include a separator